# Caching Wordpress price data in an Ionic App (before APK build)

Tags: php, android, angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

I am pulling in some data to my Ionic App via the excellent Wordpress API that contains prices that update when the page is requested in Wordpress. However, if anyone uses my App offline they 1) Won't get updated prices and 2) The page will not load.

Is there any chance I could perhaps cache the entire app pre-build so at least they will have an actual page even if accessed offline?

NB - The Wordpress complex price data is fetched via PHP and would be difficult to incorporate into the app, so API is a good way (so far)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the price data saved to local-storage then if there is a failure to connect have the code swap in the latest version that was saved. PouchDB is really useful for this.